# How to find the phase spectrum of a rectangular pulse? (Fourier Transform)

Tags: fourier-transform, homework

How to find the phase spectrum of a rectangular pulse?

[image]

The Fourier transform of a rectangular pulse

$$ x(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{for $|t| \le \tau /2$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

is given by:

$$F[x(t)]=\tau [\frac{\sin \omega(\tau /2)}{\omega (\tau /2)}]$$

---

In general, the Fourier Transform, $X(\omega)$ is id a complex valued function of $\omega$. Therefore, $X(\omega)$ can be written as:

$$X(\omega)=X_R(\omega)+jX_I(\omega)$$

The magnitude of $X(\omega)$ is given by

$$\vert X(\omega) \vert= \sqrt {(X_R(\omega))^2+(X_I(\omega))^2}$$

The phase of $X(\omega)$ is given by

$$\angle{X(\omega)}=\tan^{-1}\frac{X_I(\omega)}{X_R(\omega}$$

---

> **Question:**
>
> 1)How can we find the phase spectrum of a rectangular pulse as there doesn't appear to be any imaginary part in $X(\omega)$?
>
> 2)Why is the phase spectrum changing the way it is when we are time
>   shifting the rectangular pulse from the origin?
>
> 3) Any other insight regarding the magnitude and phase spectrum is
>   welcome.

Comment: Hint,  time shift property of FT

Answer (score 3):

For the rectangular pulse without shifting, the phase spectrum its quite simple to obtain, since its Fourier Transform $F(\omega)$ is a real function. Real functions may only lay on the real axis, thus having $0$ or $\pm \pi$ phases, depending on the positive or negative sign of the function, respectively. Try visualizing the complex plane to realize this.

Now, if you're new to DSP, for $g(t)$ it might be tricky. First, take into account the scale change when dividing by 2 in $g(t)$. This expands the spectrum by a proportion of 2, i.e. $f(t/2)$  transforms as: $2~F(2\omega)$. That's why the $sinc$ function in $g(t)$ is twice as wide as in $f(t)$. Then the amplitude is multiplied by 3, that's why $G(\omega) = 6$ for $\omega = 0$.

Due to time shifting, you'd need to multiply $F(\omega)$ by a complex exponential. Recall the time-shifting Fourier transform theorem: $f(t - t_0)$ transforms as $F(\omega)~e^{-j\omega t_0}$.

The amplitude spectrum isn't modified by a time shift (since $|e^{-j\omega t_0}| = 1$), but the phase spectrum is added to $-\omega t_0$, which is the phase of the complex exponential (i.e., $\angle e^{-j\omega t_0} = -\omega t_0$).

Finally, you'd only need to add to the phase spectrum of $f(t)$ the linear function of $\omega$: $\angle H(\omega) = -4\omega$ (since $t_0 = 4$ in this case), which has a negative slope.

That's why you have in Fig. (d) the sum of a negative-slope linear function and a rectangular pulse train of $\pm \pi$ values.

This is basic DSP, I'd recommend to take a look to these theorems at Wikipedia for a very first glance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform

Comment: You said that if the $F(\omega)$ is real the function then the phase spectrum is: _$0$ or $\pm \pi$ phases, depending on the positive or negative sign of the function, respectively._ However if we take the transform of $rect(t)$ which is $sinc({\omega\over 2})$ then we have a function which is pair and is either positive, negative or nil. However the phase spectrum is shown in the figure (c) as a rect impulse train which are positive for negative frequencies and negative for positive frequencies. Why is that ?

Comment: Ok I got it I was confused by the graph on the left which is related to $|sinc({\omega\over2})| $ while for the phase spectrum you have to use $sinc({\omega\over2})$.